# 404 Error on Xamarin Forms app when trying to connect to b2clogin for B2C local account sign-up/sign-in

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have configured an Azure B2C app [native], and am migrating my code to use b2clogin.com as well as MSAL 3.0.

My identity code kicks off the Azure B2C process on the device, but then it just 404's.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0acrl.png)
msauth.com.[MYAPPID]://auth is specified in Info.plist, and as the redirect URI.

What could cause the 404?

I'm building the PCA with below

static readonly string Tenant = $"{myappname}.onmicrosoft.com";

```
    static readonly string AppName = "myappname";
    static readonly string ClientID = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx";
    static readonly string SignUpAndInPolicy = "B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn";

    static readonly string AuthorityBase = $"https://{AppName}.b2clogin.com/{Tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    static readonly string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}?p={SignUpAndInPolicy}";

    static readonly string RedirectUrl = $"msauth.********://auth";

msaClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
           .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("mybundleid")
           .WithB2CAuthority(Authority)
           .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUrl)
           .Build();
```

Comment: have you verified the b2clogin url?

Comment: hi @Jason yes I have copied it from code and into the browser window and it lists my user flow properties

Answer (score 0):

Use [these](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#authority-for-a-b2c-tenant-and-policy) like this:

```cs
static string AuthorityBase = $"https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/";
static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{SignUpAndInPolicy}";
```